# Oauth2 login times out on AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, flask, oauth-2.0

I'm currently developing a Flask application on a Amazon EC2 instance running Linux. I have installed httpd and access to the site is successful. The Flask application has an OAuth2 authentication using Google accounts.

When testing on localhost, the website runs perfectly with the user staying logged in. However, when testing on the live site - there is a redirect to the Google login page after about a minute. Apart from this, the live site is working as expected including the actual process of logging in.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is the case or have suggestions on how to fix this? I can provide more details on the setup if need be. It seems strange that the localhost doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you're using UTC everywhere.
2. Check:

   https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=[access_token]

to see the expiration time of your access token.

Comment: I'll see if this fixes it but I'll award you the bounty for the answer first.